Is there a ROS 2 (Iron) exampe for docker available?
I've been using ROS 1 for my projects and am considering either moving away from ROS or to ROS 2. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 so I want to try it inside docker. I was not able to find easy examples using ROS 2 and docker.
Additional question: Is there a (slimmed down) pip installable version of ROS 2?

I think you could directly just run the official ros2 docker image from osrf?

I find the easiest way to run ROS 2 in a docker container is by utilizing a dev container extension in VS Code. Articulated Robotics made a video tutorial about this. You just need to choose the option "Iron" when choosing the ROS Distro.


Thanks! I'm trying it right now, seems very helpful!
